# Laravel 7 Unresolvable dependency resolving - Blade components

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I am using the new Laravel 7 Blade components. I have a new component which opens a Bootstrap delete modal like so:

```
<x-delete-modal 
    :description="$task->TaskDescription" 
    :id="$task->TaskID" 
    :route="$routeForDeleteModelModal" 
    :modelInstance="$task" 
/>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $description ]] in class App\View\Components\DeleteModal

The component looks like this:

```
 <!-- Delete Model Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    hello
</div>
```

To ensure that it wasn't the contents of the modal, I have deleted it all apart from "hello".

The DeleteModal class has 4 variables:

```
public $description;
public $id;
public $route;
public $modelInstance;
```

And it is constructed like so:

```
public function __construct($description, int $id, $route, $modelInstance)
{
    $this->description = $description;
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->route = $route;
    $this->modelInstance = $modelInstance;
}
```

I am not sure what is causing this error - I have tried making sure all my spelling is correct, reducing it down to just the description, and also doing a `dd` in the constructor, but it fails before it even gets that far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not, but the issue wasn't with the modal, it was with the HTML comment above it.

My comment was:

```
<!-- 
    ...... lots of text

    Please make sure to only include '<x-delete-modal ... />' after closing a form, as this component 
    contains a form, and HTML does not support nested form elements.
-->
```

Funnily enough, including `'<x-delete-modal ... />'` in the comment was causing it to fall over completely. Meaning that the comment was being compiled somehow. If anyone can explain why this happens I would really be interested in knowing.

The component works as expected when `'<x-delete-modal ... />'` is removed from it.

Comment: html comments are not blade comments so it will still parse the tag it finds since the html comment has no context, it is just text (i would suppose)

Comment: Therefore try to comment out with `{{-- ... --}}` in blade.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it's happening in blade files that do *not* have comments. Deleting all whitespace appears to resolve the problem. This is definitely a bug in Laravel.

Comment: I had same error but in my case I was naming an component attribute with underscore "_". I just converted to camelCase notation and it was fixed